# Is there any API to render 3D graphics+HTML 5 in Android?

Tags: android

how the default web browser in Android supports the webGL standard for rendering 3D graphics in an HTML 5 canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, only Sony Ericsson Xperia phones support webGL.